# AWS lambda Max memory used

Tags: amazon-web-services, memory, aws-lambda

I'm reading large files into a data object in memory within the lambda function. However after use of that data I have tried to dereference the object so as to free up memory.
Within the function I've tried assign it to None, {} etc. and even calling the garbage collection gc.collect(), the Max memory used is still the same.
So my question is what exactly is Max memory used reporting? Is it any memory that got touched by data whether it is still referenced or not?
And when allocating memory to the lambda function the amount you set (between 128mb and 10240mb) is it wrong to think of this as reusable memory instead I should think of it as use once?

```
import boto3
import gc

   def read_s3_file(bucket_name, file_name):
   # Create an S3 client
       s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

   # Read the file from S3
      try:
         response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name)
         content = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
         return content
    except Exception as e:
         print(f"Error reading file from S3: {e}")
         return None

   # reading both files one after the other, each file is 3gb
         bucket_name = 'myBucket'
         file_name = 'bigFile_1.txt'
         file_name_2 = 'bigFile_2.txt'

         file_content = read_s3_file(bucket_name, file_name)
         file_content = None
         gc.collect()
         file_content = read_s3_file(bucket_name, file_name_2)
```

In the example above I configured tha lambda with over 3gb of memory, I load the first 3gb file then dereference it. I then try to call the garbage collection. After that I should in theory have the memory back and have the 3gb available. But this is not the case.

Comment: Max memory is a high water mark.  Even if you free the memory later, you still used that amount of memory during the operation.  "is it wrong to think of this as reusable memory?" no, it's regular memory like any other memory.  The max memory statistic is there so you know how much memory you're actually using, not just how much you allocated.

Comment: @erik258 ok so you are saying I can reallocate memory within the lambda as it runs, however does the Max memory Used limit the use of this memory. for example If the lambda has 3gb allocated and I load into memory a 3gb file then after dereferencing the data object I cannot then load another file into memory as I have used 3gb already?

Comment: it's just memory like any memory.  If you're having trouble deallocating the memory for reuse, ask a question about that in particular giving details about your program including language and example implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Max memory used shows the “maximum” memory that was consumed during function execution. If memory usage fluctuates, it should report the maximum value it had. The memory is reusable, so if you free memory and GC collects it, you can reuse it again as usual.

Comment: But this is not the case., the memory is not available to use even after the call gc.collect()

Comment: Have you tried running this code on a local machine and comparing memory usage with lambda? Perhaps the variable is still referred and cannot be collected?

Comment: I have, I think what is happening is AWS doesn't free the memory until it is needed again  so even after dereferencing it is not until you go to use that memory that it gets freed and becomes available. Seems odd